# There exist any integer which $n$ cannot express as $(-1)^x a^2+(-1)^y b^2+(-1)^z c^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

**Problem**

Let $n,x,y,z,a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$

There exist any integer $n$ which cannot express as $(-1)^x a^2+(-1)^y b^2+(-1)^z c^2$?

Comment: Zero is clearly possible, and you can simply change the signs of all the terms if you wish, so you can assume $n$ positive if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, let $n=2k+1$, then: $$n=(k+1)^2-k^2+0^2.$$

Over to you for $n$ even.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b) (a+b)$

Comment: Can you give me little more hint.